# Why is X acting like Y?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code, it's simpler than it looks. I am just using a lot of variables to initialize the first square of my map. After that I try to make another map square, with correct dimensions, and it appears that the X is acting like Y. What I mean by that is, with the coords I am putting it should be creating a vertical line, but it is creating a horizontal one instead and it is quite puzzling to me, I see nothing wrong in the code and I am printing the coords, they seem okay.

```
var addRooms = function(map, mapSize, roomz) {
            var firstX = 20 - (Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+5);
            var firstY = 20 - (Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+5);
            var firstEndX = 20 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+5);
            var firstEndY = 20 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+5);
            var startX = 0;
            var startY = 0;
            var endX = 0;
            var endY = 0;
            var rooms = [];
            var canAdd = false;
            var lastRoom = {};

        for(var i = 0; i < roomz; i++) {
            canAdd = false;
            startX = lastRoom.midX - (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1);
            endX = startX + Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 2);
            startY = lastRoom.endY;
            endY = startY + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 5);
            if(endY > mapSize)
                endY = mapSize;
            if(endX > mapSize)
                endX = mapSize;

            var roomWidth = endX - startX;
            var roomHeight = endY - startY;
            var firstroomWidth = firstEndX - firstX;
            var firstroomHeight = firstEndY - firstY;
            var midX = (startX + Math.floor(roomWidth/2));
            var midY = (startY + Math.floor(roomHeight/2));
            var firstmidX = (firstX + Math.floor(firstroomWidth/2));
            var firstmidY = (firstY + Math.floor(firstroomHeight/2));
            //var rooms = [];
            var firstRoom = { startX: firstX, startY: firstY, endX: firstEndX, endY: firstEndY, midX: firstmidX, midY: firstmidY };

            var newRoom = { startX: startX, startY: startY, endX: endX, endY: endY, midX: midX, midY: midY };


                if(!rooms[0]) {
                    canAdd = true;
                    newRoom = firstRoom;
                    lastRoom = firstRoom;
                }
                if(!canAdd) {
                    for(var key in rooms) {
                        if(!checkIntersect(newRoom, key)) {
                            canAdd = true;
                            lastRoom = newRoom;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(canAdd) {
                    console.log(newRoom)
                    rooms.push(newRoom);
                }
        }

        for(var key in rooms) {


                for (var y = rooms[key].startY; y < rooms[key].endY; y++) {
                    for (var x = rooms[key].startX; x < rooms[key].endX; x++) {
                    if(typeof map[x][y] !== "undefined") {
                    map[x][y] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

As you can see with these coord prints it should be creating a vertical square:

```
{ startX: 14, startY: 14, endX: 27, endY: 26, midX: 20, midY: 20 }
{ startX: 19, startY: 26, endX: 22, endY: 39, midX: 20, midY: 32 }
{ startX: 18, startY: 39, endX: 21, endY: 52, midX: 19, midY: 45 }
{ startX: 17, startY: 52, endX: 19, endY: 58, midX: 18, midY: 55 }
{ startX: 17, startY: 58, endX: 20, endY: 66, midX: 18, midY: 62 }
```

Comment: Would you mind simplifying this and leaving just the piece of code that actually is causing you problems? Maybe creating a `jsFiddle` to reproduce it.

Comment: The very last for loops appear to be causing the problems, which is when it is looping through the coords that I am printing. I could attempt a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, it would make it easier for us to help you out. If you go debugging the bits you'll spot the place where the problem actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you query

```
map[x][y];
```

Like this instead?

```
map[y][x];
```

Comment: Genius.. That was my issue! I've been up a while that totally slipped past me, thank you!

Comment: My actual problem was doing this[x][y] = that[y][x] somewhere else, but your answer still helped me figure that out